# IIS challenge: Setup for global and localization sites (with geolocation) under single domain

Tags: iis-7, localization, geolocation, virtual-directory, multiple-sites

I need help solving a IIS configuration "puzzle". Here's what I have:

**1 Domain:** example.com

**4 Web folders:**

- [root]\Global - single page HTML site
- [root]\Classic1 - classic ASP site
- [root]\Classic2 - .Net 2.0 site
- [root]\Redesign - .Net 4.0 site with geolocation

Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7

**Background**

*example.com* is a website that has localized sites by country. Meaning *example.com/us* is for US users, *example.com/uk* is for European users, *example.com/AU* for Australian users, etc.

There are a total of 20 different country sites for *example.com*, where *example.com* has a single landing page with an index of country links.

**Objectives**

*Redesign* is a new site developed that is supposed to take over everything so we can get rid of the other 3 sites. It has localization with geolocation on the landing page that will determine which set of country-specific data to show on the website. Based on the country detected, it will rewrite the URL by appending the country code to the URL, like *example.com/au*.

However, I am tasked to launch *Redesign* only a few countries at a time because the data entry people need time to setup each country.

This is what needs to happen for now:

- example.com => [root]\Global
- example.com\uk => [root]\Classic1
- example.com\us => [root]\Classic2
- example.com\au => [root]\Redesign
- example.com\xx => [root]\Classic1

... and so forth.

**Problem**

First I created a site in IIS that points to [root]\Global.

Then I created a virtual directory for each country and have each points to the appropriate directory.

However, because *Redesign* has geolocation, it automatically rewrite the URL as:
example.com\au => example.com\au\us

Now, if I set *Redesign* as the global site and then the other classic sites as virtual directory, the geolocation will be in conflict with the virtual directory paths:

- example.com\us =? [root]\Redesign
- example.com\us =? [root]\Classic2

This is where I'm stuck. Anyone has any feedback and suggestions?